# Strange behaviour for data.frames without column names

Tags: r, dataframe

There is an unexpected behaviour for data.frames without column names. The following works as expected:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 5:9)
df + 1
##   a  b
## 1 2  6
## 2 3  7
## 3 4  8
```

but if we remove the column names then the behaviour is strange:

```
names(df) <- NULL
df + 1
## data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

The same is happening if the names are removed with `unname`, `setNames`. Any ideas of why this happens and is it (for some reason) expected behaviour?

**Edit**:
So it is documented that nameless `data.frame`s have unsupported results (thanks @neilfws, @Suren) but I am also interested to the why this happens. I try to find the actual c (?) code that makes this simple example to brake.

Comment: The best I can offer for now is from `?data.frame`: "The column names should be non-empty, and attempts to use empty names will have unsupported results." So in a sense it is expected, without knowing the detailed internals of how data frames work.

Comment: @Suren of course they can, e.g. `names(df) <- letters[c(1,1)];df+1`

Comment: "There is an unexpected behaviour for data.frames without column names. " What did you expect?

Comment: You could find the specific code in `Ops.data.frame` -- the 0-length "names" are used to iterate over the columns, which results in a 0-column data.frame

Answer (score 7):

In the documentation for `data.frame`, it says:

> The column names should be non-empty, and attempts to use empty names will have unsupported results.

So, it is expected that outcome may not be the desired ones if the column names are empty.

Comment: OP doesn't have empty names though but no names at all

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper aren't they the same thing?

Comment: my bad, actually, naming both columns `""` is supported, so it seems they really mean `NULL`

Comment: @Suren the names *can* be the same, this works as expected: ` data.frame(a = 1:5, a = 5:9, check.names = FALSE) + 1`

Comment: @alko989 yes, not sure why I didn't even check that. Thanks fixed it.

Comment: Actually it's still not so clear to me, od says "The column names should be non-empty", and not "the name attribute should be non-empty", so I would still think they were saying that columns named `""` are not safe and unsupported, and that the case of a `NULL` `names` attribute is undocumented.

Comment: what's interesting is that on one hand it's not just a printing issue, `df + 1` really is an empty, `data.frame`, but on the other hand the data is still in df and you can still subset it or assign new names to go back to normal : `setNames(df[1],"a")+1`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper  I changed names to `""` and tried to see if there are any unexpected outcomes - I didn't see any.

Answer (score 1):

I think this ultimately comes from the fact that R considers the `data.frame` object as a list with specific attributes:

```
## A list with no attributes
list_no_attr1 <- list(c(1,2,3), c(3,2,1))

## The attributes and class of the list
attributes(list_no_attr1)
#> NULL
class(list_no_attr1)
#> "list"
```

We can then manually add all the `data.frame` attributes without changing the structure of the `list`:

```
## Adding the names to the list (not in the attributes)
list2 <- list_no_attr1
attr(list2, "names") <- c("A", "B")

## The attributes and class of the list
attributes(list2)
#> $names
#> [1] "A" "B"
class(list2)
#> "list"

## Adding the "row.names" attributes
list3 <- list2
attr(list3, "row.names") <- c("1", "2", "3")

## The attributes and class of the list
attributes(list3)
#> $names
#> [1] "A" "B"
#> $row.names
#> [1] "1" "2" "3"

class(list3)
#> "list"
```

This is still a list. Now when we change the class of the object to `"data.frame"` and it will then use the S3 method for `data.frame` for `print` and all other associated functions

```
## Adding a data.frame class attribute
list_data_frame <- list3
attr(list_data_frame, "class") <- "data.frame"

## The attributes and class of the list
attributes(list_data_frame)
#> $names
#> [1] "A" "B"
#> $row.names
#> [1] "1" "2" "3"
#> $class
#> [1] "data.frame"

class(list_data_frame)
#> "data.frame"
```

This will now print as a proper `data.frame`. Note that it works exactly the same the way around and can transform a `data.frame` back into a `list` if we remove the class attribute.

```
## The dataframe
data_frame <-  data.frame("A" = c(1,2,3), "B" = c(3,2,1))
## The attributes and class of the list
attributes(data_frame)
#> $names
#> [1] "A" "B"
#> $row.names
#> [1] "1" "2" "3"
#> $class
#> [1] "data.frame"

class(data_frame)
#> "data.frame"

## "Converting" into a list
attr(data_frame, "class") <- NULL

attributes(data_frame)
#> $names
#> [1] "A" "B"
#> $row.names
#> [1] "1" "2" "3"

class(data_frame)
#> "list"
```

Of course it only works if the elements in the list are of the same length:

```
## Creating an unequal list with data.frame attributes
wrong_list <- list(c(1,2,3), c(3,2,1,0))
attr(wrong_list, "names") <- c("A", "B")
attr(wrong_list, "row.names") <- c("1", "2", "3")
attr(wrong_list, "class") <- "data.frame"

wrong_list
#>   A B
#> 1 1 3
#> 2 2 2
#> 3 3 1
#> Warning message:
#> In format.data.frame(x, digits = digits, na.encode = FALSE) :
#>   corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs
```

And it also bugs when omitting the `names` and `row.names` attributes as mentioned in the other comments and answers to this question:

```
## A list coerced into a data.frame without the right attributes
wrong_list <- list(c(1,2,3), c(3,2,1))
attr(wrong_list, "class") <- "data.frame"
wrong_list
#> NULL
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: That's a thorough explanation of how data.frames are lists behind the scenes. But it does not really answer the question why it breaks. The documentation clearly states that nameless data.frames are unsupported, but I wanted to know why. I would like to get a warning or that internally R would temporarily put names and then remove them before returning.